# function is not working within pipeline when using mutate

Tags: r, tidyverse

My function works on a stand alone basis, but refuses to work within a pipeline. Something is wrong with my syntax:

```
library(tidyverse)


phase1_function <- function(a1, a2, a3, a4) {

  if(any(is.na(a1), is.na(a2), is.na(a3), is.na(a4))){
    return("")  }

  if(a4 < a3){
    if(a3 < a2){
      if(a2 < a1) {"phase_1"}
    } } else {""}


}

# This works
phase1_function(1, 2, 3, NA)
phase1_function(31, 30, 29, 28)



x <- c(1:31)

# This refuses to work
data.frame(x = x) %>% 
  mutate(x1 = Hmisc::Lag(x),
           x2 = Hmisc::Lag(x1),
           x3 = Hmisc::Lag(x2)) %>%

  mutate(x4 = phase1_function(x, x1, x2, x3))
```

Please could you help me with my syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `mutate` it passes the entire column in the function hence it returns the same value for the entire column. That is equivalent to

```
phase1_function(c(1, 2), c(2, 1), c(3, 4), c(NA, 1))
#[1] ""
```

Notice how it returns only one value as output.

You need to pass the values `rowwise` in them

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(x = x) %>% 
   mutate(x1 = Hmisc::Lag(x),
          x2 = Hmisc::Lag(x1),
          x3 = Hmisc::Lag(x2)) %>%
   rowwise() %>%
  mutate(x4 = phase1_function(x, x1, x2, x3))

# A tibble: 31 x 5
#       x    x1    x2    x3 x4     
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>  
# 1     1    NA    NA    NA ""     
# 2     2     1    NA    NA ""     
# 3     3     2     1    NA ""     
# 4     4     3     2     1 phase_1
# 5     5     4     3     2 phase_1
# 6     6     5     4     3 phase_1
# 7     7     6     5     4 phase_1
# 8     8     7     6     5 phase_1
# 9     9     8     7     6 phase_1
#10    10     9     8     7 phase_1
# … with 21 more rows
```

---

If you want to avoid `rowwise` another alternative is to use `pmap` from `purrr`

```
data.frame(x = x) %>%
   mutate(x1 = Hmisc::Lag(x),
          x2 = Hmisc::Lag(x1),
          x3 = Hmisc::Lag(x2)) %>%
   mutate(x4 = pmap(list(x, x1, x2, x3), phase1_function))
```